# How to test if two dates are different using RobotFrameWork

Tags: robotframework

I wrote a code that calls a webservice twice and recover a date field called : ***lastLocationDate***. In my code I stock the two dates in two different variables date1 and date2 .

Now what I want is to make sure that my two dates are not the same.
when I log the value of my dates I have    :

```
Date1=    2019-10-08T06:54:06.118Z
Date2=    2019-10-08T06:54:05.783Z
```

I tried with substract it didn't work I am trying with not equal and looking for something ilke different.

```py
${DateFinale}=    Subtract Time From Date    ${Date2}     ${Date1}     result_format=%y-%m-%d     exculse_millies=True    date_Format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f
```

I have also tried to add the later Z in the code it dodn't work too

```py
date_Format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
```

I axpected a TimeDate but I got this mesage:
        KEYWORD ${DateFinale} = DateTime . Subtract Time From Date ${Date2}, ${Date1}, result_format=%y-%m-%d, exculse_millies=True, date_Format=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f
Documentation:
Subtracts time from date and returns the resulting date.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20191008 09:08:18.494 / 20191008 09:08:18.494 / 00:00:00.000
09:08:18.494    FAIL    Keyword 'DateTime.Subtract Time From Date' got positional argument after named arguments.

Comment: Why jenkins and squash tags?

Comment: If you have read the `DateTime` library documentation, you can see that you cannot use DateTime format as the second parameter in `Subtract Time From Date`. The documentation says that  "Time that is subtracted in one of the supported time formats". However, using date format is perfectly fine with `Subtract Date From Date` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it this way:

`${isdateequal}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  Should Be Equal  ${date1}  ${date2}`

`Run Keyword If '${isdateequal}' == 'True' Test Failed`

Comment: Cannot compare True with 'True'...

If you already have a boolean value in a variable, you can simply do `Run Keyword If    ${isdateequal}    Test Failed`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot the ' ' after Run Keyword If, i corrected it

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I didn't have to use the substract

Comment: @Hopeful, then mark the answer as "accepted answer": https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version than earlier answer:

```
Compare Dates Are Different
    ${date1}=    Get Current Date
    ${date2}=    Get Current Date
    Run Keyword If    '${date1}' == '${date2}'    Fail    Dates are same
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to solve the problem All I had to do is to compare my dates as Strings

```
    Should Not Be Equal As Strings    ${Date1}    ${Date2}    msg=Aucune localisation n'a été recue
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would use Evaluate Keyword

```
${date1}=    Convert Date    2019-10-08T06:54:06.118Z
${date2}=    Convert Date    2019-10-08T06:54:05.783Z
${date_same}=    Evaluate    '${date1}' == '${date2}'
Log    ${date_same}
Should Not Be True    ${date_same}
```